# INSTR not searching a string properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using INSTR to search for a substring (on a specific position) within a string. However if does not seem to search properly.  I verified that part_no column is a STRING type.

Here is the code:

```
select part_no,
case 
  when instr(part_no, '1', 4,1) = 4 then 'Con' 
    when instr(part_no, '2', 4,1) = 4 then 'Pairs' 
    when instr(part_no, '3', 4,1) = 4 then 'Tri'
    end as Part_Type
from INV_PART
```

Here is the result:

```
 PART_NO         PART_TYPE
 
 26010U180700710    
 2V010U080250416    
 2V010U080310H00    
 7P022U161557700    
 80110M060300790 Conductor
```

Wondering why it does not classify the other parts i.e. 1st three should be 'Con' and 4th Should be 'Pairs'?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The code list can't produce output given, since in no case is the output `'Conductor'`. See also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88bdad/1, the query appears to work as expected at least with the first part number. (If you had included text, instead of a picture, for example output, I could have cut and pasted it into the SQL Fiddle and tested all the cases given.)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit it, wasn't what I wanted to look like, but the picture is removed now.

Comment: Okay. Take a look at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/994cf/1. With the `PART_NO` data in your example and your query, the `PART_TYPE` result is not what you have shown. (SQL Fiddle is a way to share and run small examples of SQL.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me. I am really puzzled with this as well, because I did a similar test as you did - i.e. adding a WHERE part_no = to a part_no that I know it exist and it's working properly.

Comment: However when I run it with no where clause I get the same as I shared initially.

Comment: 1) The code given **cannot** produce the output shown. There is no way to have a `part_type` of `'Conductor'`. That is not a possible output. 2) I assume the example is simplified from some more complex code. So this suggestion may not hold, but `INSTR` is the wrong tool. The code is looking at the character at position 4. Use `SUBSTR` instead. `case substr(part_no, 4, 1)  when '1' then 'Con' when '2' then  Pairs' when '3' then 'tri' end as part_type`.

Comment: One place to look, is use `DUMP` to get a more exact look at the `part_no` values in the rows where your expression is not working. Maybe there are leading space throwing the location off. Or a unicode character that looks like a `'1'` but isn't.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635

Comment: Actually, I will have to plug this to another more complex query. I developed this to explore the options. SUBSTR is working well except for those first 4-5 part numbers (same as INSTR) for some reason. The rest is fine it picks up properly. I suspect the same, something wrong with the type/encoding of the characters.